# Running a script in a Linux directory

Tags: linux

I am quite new to Linux but am enjoying it.  I am a level above a directory called `dao_all`.  In the dao_all directory I have a script I would like to run called `make_pyc_package.sh` which will produce another folder (with output in a new directory called `pkg`).

I am trying to run the code as follows:

```
./dao_all/make_pyc_package.sh pkg
```

However when I run this I get the following output:

```
-bash: ./: Is a directory
```

Comment: are you sure you cannot run script and this error is not created by running script? I think something in script creates this problem because I ran something like that right now and it works.

Comment: You need to provide the script and the full output of the script. Also see [How to use Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 0):

I only can think of 2 situations that can create that error:

1. there is a ' ' (space) at start of `dao_all` and we cannot see it in the code you posted. In that case you get that error.
2. error is created by script. I mean script will run, but creates that error while running.

Answer (score -1):

coud you use change directory command to switch directory to "dao_all" and then run the script ,try following commands to do so
```

```
cd dao_all - "change to dao_all directory"
ls - "just to check if you have make_pyc_package.sh"
if you see make_pyc_package.sh on ls command ,then run the script by
./make_pyc_package.sh
```

``

Comment: also make sure  "make_pyc_package.sh"  file is an executable file